# GEV does not fit properly

Tags: python, data-fitting

I have yearly maxima for which I tried doing a GEV-analysis. However, when trying, the pdf does not fit the data at all. I tried minimizing like proposed at similar questions but this did not work as well. The code can be found below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import genextreme

yearly_max = [3465, 3461, 3318, 3304, 3211, 3307, 3224, 3440, 3317, 3393, 3360, 3695,
            3265, 3328, 3326, 3272, 3479, 3275, 3355, 3316, 3324, 3411, 3298, 3424,
            3311, 3387, 3374, 3320, 3307, 3343, 3440]

shape_gev, location_gev, scale_gev = genextreme.fit(yearly_max)

input_WL = np.linspace(2000, 6000, 1000)
pdf_gev = genextreme.pdf(input_WL, shape_gev, loc=location_gev, scale=scale_gev)
plt.hist(yearly_max, bins=40, range=(3000, 4000), density = True, label="normed occurence")
plt.plot(input_WL, pdf_gev, linewidth=4, label='pdf')
```

Can someone please help me solving this problem?